# How to wipe a partition quickly with value zero?

Tags: filesystems, partition, dd, disk, shred

I want to wipe a partition quickly.I search the answer in website.
such as:
  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=16M count=96`

`shred -v -z -n 1 /dev/sda1`

**But**:

All the commandline,will overwrite with value zero though there is zero.
  I think in the partition somewhere have value,but somewhere also have zero.

**Want**:
   Just use commandline but not GUN.**Because ddrescue Need to** **compile** and install

`dd` or `shred` or other command just overwrite zero to where that there's value is not zero in a partition in Linux.

---

Update:

My understand is in below

Now:

```
ddrescue -b 1572864 --generate-mode /dev/zero /dev/sda1 flash.map 
// This will create a flash.map 

ddrescue -b 1572864 --force --fill-mode=+ /dev/zero /dev/sda1 flash.map
//will to fill the patition by flash.map 
//1572864byte =16M*96
```

It's right?What about my understand？

Comment: I am sorry. I got it.My understand is in below
Now:

ddrescue -b 1572864 --generate-mode /dev/zero /dev/sda1 flash.map 
// This will create a flash.map

ddrescue -b 1572864--force --fill-mode=+ /dev/zero /dev/sda1 flash.map
//will to fill the patition by flash.map

//1572864byte =16M*96
It's right?What about my understand？
Thanks Zchme, Kamil Maciorowski!

Comment: This `1572864` certainly looks wrong. It should probably be either `512` or `4096`.

Comment: I don't understand.I have watch the manual about ddrescue 


-b bytes
--sector-size=bytes
Sector (hardware block) size of input device in bytes

So my patition size is 16M*96 =1572864byte 

I have no idea.And I want a not  need to compile and install commandline.

Thanks Kamil Maciorowski again!

Comment: (1) Sector size and partition size are two different things. (2) Is 16M*96 really 1572864 bytes? (is 16M in your calculation 16MiB or what?) (3) Either way the partition seems relatively small (right?); if so, I wouldn't bother and I would just write zeros to the entire partition.

Comment: Thanks Kamil Maciorowski! I got it.I am sorry for the website rules.I will follow it.